# SQL statement select always the same field, even if the statement search for other

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM accounts
WHERE limitedLogins > 0  AND valA < valB AND lastLogin < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND loginAmount <  maxLogins
OR limitedLogins <= 0 AND valA < valB
ORDER BY valA DESC LIMIT 1
```

It sort of work, but, it does not have the behavior I need:

if I have a table as follow:

```
id | limitedLogins | valA | valB | lastLogin | maxLogins | loginAmount
1  |       5       |   2  |  10  |3 hour ago |     5     |      1
2  |       0       |   1  |  10  |   null    |     5     |      1
```

The query will ignore the field id 1, and will always select the id 2, but it should select id 1 instead, as it comes before the 2 and valA is bigger (ORDER by DESC)

if instead the table is like this:

```
id | limitedLogins | valA | valB | lastLogin | maxLogins | loginAmount
1  |       5       |   1  |  10  |3 hour ago |     5     |      1
2  |       0       |  11  |  10  |   null    |     5     |      1
```

Then the query will select the id 1, as valA is bigger than valB in id 2.
It seems it will execute only the second OR statement, and execute the first only if the second is not found. But I tried inverting the checks, and the result is the same. So the ORDER BY is totally ignored and only one record is always selected

What's the issue there?

----EDIT---

Seems this query:

```
limitedLogins > 0  AND valA < valB AND lastLogin < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND loginAmount <  maxLogins
```

Is always ignored or executed by last, while I need it to be executed in same time/or before the other

I've tried this:

```
WHERE (limitedLogins > 0  AND valA < valB AND lastLogin < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND loginAmount <  maxLogins)
OR (limitedLogins <= 0 AND valA < valB)
```

And I've tried this:

```
WHERE (limitedLogins <= 0 AND valA < valB)
OR (limitedLogins > 0  AND valA < valB AND lastLogin < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND loginAmount <  maxLogins)
```

The result does not change, the shorter query is always executed first, ignoring the other, thus the ORDER by doesn't select the correct value

Comment: AND /OR : check the rules of precedence, and maybe add some parentheses.

Comment: @wildplasser I am not expert on SQL sadly, could you enlighten me on what you mean? Thank you

Comment: In example 1: `ORDER BY valA DESC LIMIT 1` means take the highest valA row that meets the `WHERE` clause.  That means valA = 2 is returned with the `LIMIT 1`.  Do you understand this now?  If you wish to pick valA = 1 first, remove the `DESC` order term.

Comment: @JonArmstrong No, if you read what I wrote on the first example, in fact ValA = 2 is never returned, instead it returns ValA = 1, thus ORDER BY is always ignored

Comment: and just to be clear, as mentioned by @wildplasser, your `WHERE` clause logic is this: `WHERE (expression) OR (expression)`, since the `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, just as `*` has higher precedence than `+` in simple numeric/math expressions.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Ok but even adding the parenthesis, the result is the same, the first query is always ignored unless the second is not met

Comment: Create a complete test case that is executable.  What you wrote doesn't seem to agree with your last comment.  I'll need to see more concrete example, since your descriptions seem to be in conflict with each other.  You initially said your SQL didn't do what you expect and `The query will ignore the field id 1`.  That's NOT true because of the `ORDER BY DESC` logic.

Comment: Try using dbfiddle.uk for your test case.  I may help if you have problems doing that.

Comment: @JonArmstrong can I message on private so I can link you the db etc?

Comment: `The result does not change, the shorter query is always executed first, ignoring the other, thus the ORDER by doesn't select the correct value`  ... It's a boolean expression.  For `x OR y` if `x` is true `y` doesn't matter. For `x AND y`, if `x` is false or null, `y` doesn't matter.  It's just the way boolean logic behaves.

Comment: Feel free to contact me.  But we can easily create a simple fiddle to show the behavior.

Comment: Note: Your date/time comparison logic will always fail (be null, or behave as false) for a null lastLogin.  Maybe that's also causing confusion.  Here's the test case: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=96ed9154998b759bf6a9608c16ce8964`

Comment: Sorry. The test case data was incorrect: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be5be2b78896dd5e9e121dda77ff43be`  ... If you have questions about that result, just ask.

Comment: @JonArmstrong https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8T1ivJvXKi8e1zv3qpdi5P/1  as you can see it won't work, it will always return abc2, it will only return abc1 if abc2 is not found by valA

Comment: Can you please explain the `intended logic / requirement`?  Your incorrect SQL can't be used to explain the requirement.

Comment: @JonArmstrong the correct behavior of the SQL would be: if the first query doesn't produce a result/nothing is met, then the second query should be checked

Comment: Let's examine the two logic expressions.  One moment.  I'll update the test case.

Comment: Check this fiddle, and my comments in the last panel: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5cba86204c1da310eed01834293c4e1`

Comment: Notice: `expr1` and `expr2` show the boolean result of each side of the `OR` expression.

Comment: These are not statements, but expressions.  Each row passes the `WHERE` clause if the logic of the `WHERE` clause produces `true` for that row.  Both rows pass with your logic.  That means the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` will drive which row is seen in the result.  If that's not clear enough, we might need to visit a more basic tutorial.

Comment: Notice in this updated fiddle, I added a panel with parenthesis around the two terms of the `OR` expression.  `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fdb86d53b9adef34db8bf71d692b241`   ... The meaning is the same, so the result is the same.

Comment: @JonArmstrong the last update example works. I don't know why the others don't. mistery of mysql i suppose

Comment: Only the first panel with your SQL has the original `ORDER BY`, which I suspect is the mistake.  The next panel contains my adjustment to the `ORDER BY`, which produces what you wanted, just for this test data.  The rest of the panels have no `ORDER BY` and no `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: Notice, you never showed the exact expected result.  It's tough to guess.